# How to Fix Image Padding and Spacing in HTML Emails?

Tags: html, html-email

I am working on HTML email template. There is a small spacing below the image and I am not able to get rid of it. And this space is caused by the DOCTYPE is all I know.

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iidp5.png)

I tried everything possible like:

- Adding style="display:block" to the image.
- Setting the "Align" Attribute to "absmiddle", "absbottom", "texttop", "middle", "left", "right" and "top".
- Setting the Line-Height to 10px or Less by placing the image in div.
- Setting Font-Size to 2px or Less.
- Using Float:Left or Float:Right.

But nothing seemed to work for me. Can anyone help me figure it out please ?

I having been trying to figure it out for the past two days :P

I have attached the sample code below:

```
<div style="background:#ffffff;background-color:#ffffff;margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;">
    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="background:#ffffff;background-color:#ffffff;width:100%;">
       <tbody>
         <tr>
          <td style="direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:0px;text-align:center;">
          <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
          <tr>
            <td class="" style="vertical-align:top;width:600px;">
              <div class="mj-column-px-600 mj-outlook-group-fix" style="font-size:0px;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:100%;">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="vertical-align:top;" width="100%">
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center" style="font-size:0px;padding:0px;word-break:break-word;">
                      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td style="width:600px;">
                              <a href="#">
                                <img src="./assets/img/hero@3x.png" style="border:0;display:block;outline:none;text-decoration:none;height:auto;width:100%;font-size:13px;" />
                              </a>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
         </table>
       </td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't see any spacing below image. Image is centered in the page. Be more clear what you want and share some more code

Comment: Check out [Cerberus](https://tedgoas.github.io/Cerberus/) if you don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Are you talking about the space above the image? Or are you seeing space below the image in a certain email client?

Comment: There is space below the image. I can be fixed by giving margin:-1px but email clients does not support negative css margins.

Comment: What browser/email client are you viewing it in? I don't see any space in Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: Could you post a screen shot with the extra space?

Comment: I am using Chrome and Gmail

Comment: Found it. The problem was with the image itself. It had extra space below it.